# Add a property of users of 'group'

Tags: feature-request, users

Thought of this in relation to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15937/is-a-localized-tag-acceptable-on-stackoverflow).

How about creating a property of users called 'group' that could be searched on, so that different groups of users could find posts by each other.  So all the 'R' people could have their own group, or as in the linked question, users all in the same class could all have that 'group' attached to themselves, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I understand the concerns about abuse but personally I think this could be a really powerful feature.  Imagine you have a network of remote people working on an open source project.  All these people could join the development team for that project and then receive notification if any of them are facing issues.

- If its a broad project then the issues may span any number of tags so following them doesn't help
- If the community is fluid then you can't follow user ids because people are constantly joining and leaving

To avoid abuse simply have a rule that you can't vote for someone in the same team as you

Comment: This is a *great* rationale for the more social features of... Github.

Answer (score 8):

Not a networking site.

Comment: ...and you'll end up with "join our coop and we'll agree to up-vote each other."

Comment: `voyager` is inviting you to join SO Mafia Wars!

Answer (score 8):

That... sounds like an open invitation to abuse, cliquishness, etc.

If you really want to keep track of a group of users, then make a note of their IDs. It's really quite trivial to aggregate activity feeds from multiple users via Google Reader and its ilk.

But let's keep SO proper free of that sort of thing...

Comment: Heh... "Keep"... Now i'm the one being pollyannaish...

Answer (score 0):

You can just search for all the questions tagged 'r' (or follow its RSS feed) without the need to tie it to users.