# Raindrops keep tagging on SO

Tags: discussion, tags

The [Raindrop wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Raindrop/Community) on Mozilla tells developers:

> Specific code questions can be asked via [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Use "[raindrop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raindrop)" as a tag on the question.

What's the official (and your) stand on that? I wouldn't consider this blatant abuse (as e.g. in the riacowboy case), and it's also not such a definite "no" as in the [tufts-comp40](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15937/is-a-localized-tag-acceptable-on-stackoverflow) case, but on the other hand SO probably doesn't want to become a developer mailing list replacement.

And questions specifically about rainbow code might become candidates for "too localized"---or would they?

What do you think?

Comment: +1 For now the song is stuck running notes inside the head.

Answer (score 9):

If they hadn't have told people to do that, what would people tag their questions with? `raindrop`, of course. They're just telling people who don't understand SO how they should ask their questions, and there's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 5):

My thoughts is that it is *potentially* a programming technology, and as long as people are asking genuine programming questions I'm content. I wouldn't want to see product support questions *outside* of programming.

So far there is only one example of a raindrop question, and it doesn't seem to be hugely programming related. I'm inclined to give the tag the benefit of the future doubt...

Answer (score 1):

I think there was another project that moved most of their "support" to StackOverflow, and I think Jeff and Joel mentioned it as a good thing on the podcast.  I think it's a good thing to get people working on that project participating in SO because they'll have expertise on other things as well.